# Are there any EventBrokers available for WinRT?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, c#-5.0

I'm trying to find some event broker implementation that has been ported to WinRT, instead of writing my own. I was hoping that something like Prism's IEventAggregator or bbvEventBroker has already been ported to WinRT, however I haven't found anything - yet. Therefore I was hoping for some hints, anyone seen anything available for WinRT yet?

Cheers ;)

**Edit**

Results fund thus far :

[Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator)

[MVVM Toolkit Messenger](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b922e8ccf674#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/Win8RP/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Win8/Messaging/Messenger.Win8.cs) (Thanks to Filip Skaun)

[EventAggregator.NET](https://github.com/staxmanade/EventAggregator.Net)

[Rx Framework based EventAggregator](http://joseoncode.com/2010/04/29/event-aggregator-with-reactive-extensions/) (Rx works on RT)

Keep'em coming, let's see what else is out there :)

Answer (score 1):

MVVM Light has the Messenger thing. The only problem is it does not have support for weak event tracking yet, so you need to Unregister() from the events you Register()-ed to when your class is not used anymore.

http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b922e8ccf674#GalaSoft.MvvmLight%2fWin8RP%2fGalaSoft.MvvmLight.Win8%2fMessaging%2fMessenger.Win8.cs